# How to update the FlatList immediately after state changed?

Tags: react-native, state, listitem

I am working with react native.

I have component listing by using

And, when the state to give data to update the list change. It won't update immediately. It take few seconds to re-render.

so, how can I update the component immeidately

```
//Listcomponent

const ListGlossary = ({glossaries, onPressGlossary, navigation, searchField}) => {

  return (

 <FlatList
          data={glossaries}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.key}
          renderItem={({item}) => 
            <TouchableHighlight 
              onPress = {() => navigation.navigate('DetailGlossaryScreen', { searchField: searchField, word: item.word, translate: item.translate})}>
            <ListItem
              key={`${item.key}`} 
              title={`${item.word}`}
            />
            </TouchableHighlight>
          }
        />
}
```

//And you can find here the home screen component

```
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoading: true, 
      glossaries: [],
      searchField: '',
    }   
  }
   componentDidMount () {
Promise.resolve().then(() => {this.setState({glossaries: JSONDataFromFile, isLoading: false})})

}
onSearchChange = (inputText) => {
    this.setState({searchField: inputText});
  }
render(){
  return(

let filteredWords = []
if(this.state.searchField != null) {

    let searchField = this.state.searchField.toLowerCase(),
    glossaries = this.state.glossaries;               
    for(let i = 0, l = glossaries.length; i < l; ++i) {
        if(glossaries[i].word.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchField) === 0){
            filteredWords.push(glossaries[i]);
        }
    }
} 

{this.state.isLoading ?
          <View style={{flex: 1, paddingTop: 20}}>
            <ActivityIndicator />
          </View>
        :
          <ListGlossary 
            navigation = {this.props.navigation} 
            glossaries = {filteredWords}
            onPressGlossary={this.onPressGlossary}
            searchField = {this.state.searchField}
          />
        }
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please show the whole component, and give the length of the list.

--- Edit

I suspect you're doing too much work in the render function. You're filtering every time it gets called, and since you're passing in the `navigation` prop (I assume you're using `React-Navigation`), it'll get called frequently. If you're using a stack navigator, all the other screens are also getting re-rendered every time you navigate to a new screen. Avoid passing `navigation` as much as possible, or use a HOC composition to ignore it.

You probably don't need to be filtering glossaries every time the user changes the search value. Use the `shouldComponentUpdate` lifecycle method.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: I wrote this gist which expands on my answer about the `navigation` prop. It's especially for an older version of react-navigation but mostly still applies to the new version:

https://gist.github.com/lucas1richard/e720015613ec1de4dfdb59168f39fa41

Comment: I am new to react-native and never use redux. would you mind give me more clear way to implement this. Thank you :)